# How to draw a link arrow with texttable

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

```
% PDCA cycle

% Author: tikzanfaenger, Helmut, and Bartman
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>
\begin{comment}
:Title: PDCA cycle
:Tags: Diagrams;Decorations;Arcs
:Author: Helmut
:Slug: pdca-cycle

A diagram of the PDCA cycle. Collaborative work of
tikzanfaenger, Helmut, and Bartman at
http://golatex.de/pdca-zyklus-mit-tikz-t16195.html
\end{comment}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{208,208,208}
\definecolor{mymagenta}{RGB}{226,0,116}
\newcommand*{\mytextstyle}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{black!85}}
\newcommand{\arcarrow}[3]{%
   % inner radius, middle radius, outer radius, start angle,
   % end angle, tip protusion angle, options, text
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rin}{1.7}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rmid}{2.2}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rout}{2.7}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\astart}{#1}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\aend}{#2}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\atip}{5}
   \fill[mygray, very thick] (\astart+\atip:\rin)
                         arc (\astart+\atip:\aend:\rin)
      -- (\aend-\atip:\rmid)
      -- (\aend:\rout)   arc (\aend:\astart+\atip:\rout)
      -- (\astart:\rmid) -- cycle;
   \path[
      decoration = {
         text along path,
         text = {|\mytextstyle|#3},
         text align = {align = center},
         raise = -1.0ex
      },
      decorate
   ](\astart+\atip:\rmid) arc (\astart+\atip:\aend+\atip:\rmid);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \fill[even odd rule,mymagenta] circle (1.5);

   \node at (0,0) [
      font  = \mytextstyle,
      color = white,
      align = center
   ]{
      PDCA\\
      Cycle
   };
   \arcarrow{ 85}{  3}{ PLAN  }
   \arcarrow{270}{357}{ DO    }
   \arcarrow{182}{269}{ CHECK }
   \arcarrow{176}{ 96}{ ACT   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[Source of the above code](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pdca-cycle). How to change the picture so it is like the following :
[image]

Comment: If this is a one-off, just draw 4 hexagons and put text in the centers.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of shape is a `signal, signal from=west`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    myarrow/.style={signal, signal from=west, draw, fill=#1, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=2cm},
    node distance=2mm]

\node[myarrow=yellow!30](a){First};
\node[myarrow=green!30, right=of a](b){Second};
\node[myarrow=cyan!30, right=of b](c){Third};
\node[myarrow=red!30, right=of c](d){Fourth};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]